# Multi field analyzer not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm confused. I have the following document indexed:

```
    POST test/topic
    {
      "title": "antiemetics"
    }
```

With the following query:

```
    {
        "query": { 
                        "query_string" : {
                            "fields" : ["title*"],
                            "default_operator": "AND", 
                            "query" :"anti emetics",
                            "use_dis_max" : true
                        }
                    },
                   "highlight" : {
                        "fields" : {
                            "*" : {
                                "fragment_size" : 200,
                                "pre_tags" : ["<mark>"],
                                "post_tags" : ["</mark>"]
                            }
                        }
                    }
    }
```

and the following settings and mappings:

```
     POST test{
           "settings":{
              "index":{
                 "number_of_shards":1,
                 "analysis":{
                    "analyzer":{
                       "merge":{
                          "type":"custom",
                          "tokenizer":"keyword",
                          "filter":[
                             "lowercase"
                          ],
                          "char_filter":[
                             "hyphen",
                             "space",
                             "html_strip"
                          ]
                       }
                    },
                    "char_filter":{
                       "hyphen":{
                          "type":"pattern_replace",
                          "pattern":"[-]",
                          "replacement":""
                       },
                       "space":{
                          "type":"pattern_replace",
                          "pattern":" ",
                          "replacement":""
                       }
                    }
                 }
              }
           },
           "mappings":{
              "topic":{
                 "properties":{
                    "title":{
                       "analyzer":"standard",
                       "search_analyzer":"standard",
                       "type":"string",
                       "fields":{
                          "specialised":{
                             "type":"string",
                             "index":"analyzed",
                             "analyzer":"standard",
                             "search_analyzer":"merge"
                          }
                       }
                    }
                 }
              }
           }
        }
```

I know my use of a multi-field doesn't make sense as I'm using the same index analyzer as the title so please just ignore that however I'm more interested in my understanding with regard to analyzers. I was expecting the merge analyzer to change the following query "anti emetics" to "antiemetics" and I was hoping the multifield setting that has the analyzer applied would match against the token "antiemetics" but I don't get any results back even though I have tested that the analyzer is removing white spaces from the query by running the analyze API. Any idea why?

Comment: What version of ES you are using?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work with your setup:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "title.specialised": "anti emetics"
      }
   }
}
```

Here's some code I set up to play with it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/3ef6926644213cf7db568557a801fec6cb15eaf9

Comment: many thanks, I was hoping to use the query_string option but it seems like because of the way it works it's not possible to use a search_analyzer with it.